# Adding value to existing value in registry (updating it)

Tags: windows, powershell

What should i use for adding at the end of key new entry (instead of rewriting it)?

For example existing registry value:

```
path = c:\windows;c:\folder
```

what i would like to add at the end:

```
path = c:\windows;c:\folder;c:\folder2
```

just adding c:\folder2 at the end of key "path"

It should be .reg or .bat file.

Comment: Isn't that just reading it, adding the new part to it, and writing it again? You can't use a .reg file for this, and if you're using powershell then your .bat file should just invoke a powershell script file - see [Use PowerShell to Easily Modify Registry Property Values](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-easily-modify-registry-property-values/)

Comment: You seem to be mixing terminology.  Registry _keys_ contain one or more _values_, each of which has corresponding _data_.  Thus, it appears `path` is a _value_ and you want to append to the existing _data_, correct?  Also, are you really just trying to modify the `%PATH%` environment variable?  Why do you ask for either a `.reg` or `.bat` file (kind of a big difference) but then tag the question with [tag:PowerShell]?

Comment: from what i can tell, you cannot _append_ to a registry value. you must re-write it.

Comment: @BACON true - i would like to add new data to existing data in value path. 
im asking for reg, bat or even powershell script, thats why i added powershell tag.

Comment: @stuartd  so as i can see i need to :
1) read data from value
2) add new data to existing data
3) write new data to value

Answer (score 1):

This would be quite easy with PowerShell. You could just get the current value and append the string. Here is an example of doing this to a REG_SZ value under HKEY_CURRENT_USER:
(NOTE: "exec" is the name of the REG_SZ property.

```powershell
$Path = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Azureus" -Name "exec"
$UpdatedValue = $Path.exec + ";C:\folder2"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path.PSPath -Name "exec" -Value $UpdatedValue
```